# Finding Maxima or Minima on real measurements

Tags: calculus

I have done some measurements of time taken to execute an algorithm, and the following are the execution times in milli seconds (ms).  [13.5, 14, 12, 14, 14, 12, 14, 14, 12, 14,13.9,12... etc]. I took the derivative (difference)  of this measurements to know the rate of change, and I got [0.5, -2,  2, 0, -2,  2, 0, -2, 2, -0.1 -1.9]. 
But I can't find an equation like y=mx for this kind of measurements, which will help in finding the derivative of measurements.

If I want to find the maxia or minima,  I should know the equation, then I can equate the derivative of that equation to zero, to find where the maxima or minima.

So, is there a way to easily find at what point the maxima or minima has happened ?

-ben

Comment: The $f'(x)=0$ thing only applies to differentiable (and thus, continuous) functions. Your function is discrete.

Comment: But by taking difference we could know what is the rate of change. Is there any other method to find maxima or minima without graphing

Comment: Find a point where the value is either greater than values immediately to the left and to the right, or less than values to the left and to the right...